# Why "argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' "?

Tags: typescript

Trying to get type from Record, but something gone wrong:

```
export function stateFilter<
        KState extends keyof typeof stateConfig,
        KType extends keyof typeof stateConfig[KState], 
        KEvent extends keyof typeof stateConfig[KState][KType]
    >(
        state: KState,
        type: KType,
        event: KEvent
    ) {
    
}
    
stateFilter("default", "commands", "" /* Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345) */);
    
const stateConfig: Record<statesList, MapModel> = {
    "default": {
        "commands": {
            "/start": startGreetings,
            "/ping": pingCalculation,
            "/help": helpMessage,
            "default": unknownCommand
        }
    },
    "start": {
        "message": {
            "default": pingCalculation
        }
    }
}

interface MapModel {
    commands?: {
        [key in SlashCommands | "default"]?: functionModel
    }
    callback?: {
        [key in string | "default"]?: functionModel
    }
    message?: {
        [key in string | "default"]?: functionModel
    }
}

type functionModel = (client: Client, event: Update) => Promise<statesList | void>;

export type statesList = "start" | "default";

export type SlashCommands = "/start" | "/help" | "/ping";
```

TS error on 3rd argument (need "/start" | "/ping" | "/help" ...):

> Type '"request"' cannot be
> used to index type 'RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]'.ts(2536)

Comment: Please provide the types of the commands and default message constants so that we may have a minimal production to work with.

Comment: Please reduce your example to [this code](//tsplay.dev/werGXN), as the rest of it is mostly just distracting from the issue, which is that `MapModel`'s properties are all optional and so possibly `undefined`. You can't index into a maybe-`undefined`; it has no known-good keys, so `keyof` it is `never`.  A possible fix looks like [this](//tsplay.dev/WGRLVm) where you strip off the `undefined` from the type before indexing into it.  If this addresses your issue I can write up an answer after you [edit] the code to be minimal. If not, what am I missing? Please mention @jcalz if you reply to me.

Comment: @jcalz Its ok, but Im need types actually from stateConfig (not type). Ive showed what I want [here](https://tsplay.dev/wglYlN)

Comment: That's a separate issue; you can't annotate something as a (non-union) type and have the compiler remember something more specific than that about a value you assign. Don't annotate if you want more specific typings.  If you don't annotate and let the compiler infer then [you get this behavior](https://tsplay.dev/WYZb3w).  So which is your main issue?  That optional properties cannot be indexed into? Or that you annotated a variable and then wanted information that the annotation doesn't contain?  Which fix is closer to what you want?